# BIRT show a series as a bar in line graph

Tags: birt

I am doing some crime analysis and creating a chart. On x axis, I am plotting crime types, on y axis, we have crime count and on legend (Y values grouping) we have towns. Please check the attached image BIRT.jpg which has everything in a line graph

This is the chart I created in BIRT. Now I would like to change the **My Town** line to a Bar. so that I can compare **My Town** against the rest of the town. For example, see the Bar and line.jpg where My Town is shown as a Bar

[image: BIRT line chart]

[image: BAR and line graph example that I want to do in BIRT]

Thanks for your help

Regards

Syed

Comment: Is it the same question as your previous ones, i.e. you know how to create two series but each serie displays all legend items? There is probably something to do with "beforeDrawLegendItem" script of the chart, i will give it a try on my side.

Comment: Yes, I tried two separate Y axis, Y axis1 for My town and setting it up as Bar and Y axis2 for other towns but the problem was that I was seeing all towns in both series in legend. Then I tried a single series and tried to see if there was any possibility to do it using a single series, but none of the methods are working for me. I have done it easily in Qlikview as you can see in second image but I am not an expert in BIRT and am having hard time to do it in BIRT

Comment: Please let me know If you do it using the beforedrawlegenditem function in script. I will really appreciate it. I am really stuck in it

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example near from what you need.  In the picture below, we make use of two series:

- a serie "area" to represent a selected country
- a serie "line" to represent countries to compair

It also works with a barchart instead of the area, unfortunately mixing barcharts and line series does not render very well when we make use of a "Y-series grouping".

[image]

This report is available online [here](http://www.visioneo.org/economic-country-detail). As you can see legend items are displayed as expected, because they are filtered in "beforeDrawLegendItem" event. I don't know why this feature is not natively supported, may be you should report a bug in Eclipse bugzilla for this. It seems the only way allowing to recognize which items should be hidden, is to use color palettes: here we set all colors we want to keep as "gradients", and we leave others as simple colors. That's really tricky but it works.

**A prerequisite** is, the selected item ("My town" in your case) should be the first row: in "Optional Y-series grouping", enter a sort expression so that this specific item will be the first one.

Then:

- in the color palette of the area serie, only the first color is set as gradient
- in the color palette of the line serie, all colors are set as gradient except the first one

Here is the script "**beforeDrawLegendItem**"

```
function beforeDrawLegendItem( lerh, bounds, icsc )
{
  try{
    var gradient=lerh.getFill().getClass().isAssignableFrom(GradientImpl);

    if (!gradient){ //not a gradient, we must hide this legend item
      bounds.setWidth(0);
      bounds.setHeight(0);
      lerh.getLabel().setVisible(false);
    }else{
      lerh.getLabel().setVisible(true);
    }
  }catch(e){

  }

}
```